# Single row for multiple case in a select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a solution for the below senario

I have a table temp with columns: `a, b, c, d` and the data looks like this:

### **TABLE TEMP**

```
+---+----+----+----+
|a  |  b |  c |  d |
+===+====+====+====+
| 1 | 1  | 1  |  m |
| 1 | 2  | 1  |  d |
| 1 | 3  | 1  |  w |
| 2 | 1  | 1  |  m |
| 2 | 2  | 1  |  d |
| 2 | 2  | 1  |  w |
+---+----+----+----+
```

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN B=1 AND C=1 THEN D END as T1,
CASE WHEN B=2 AND C=1 THEN D END as T2,
CASE WHEN B=3 AND C=1 THEN D END as T3
FROM TEMP
WHERE A=1
```

The above query gives multiple rows with null values where value is not present

I need a result set with a single row that looks like this:

### **Expected Result**

```
+------+-------+------+
| T1   |   T2  |  T3  |
+======+=======+======+
| m    |   d   |  w   |
+------+-------+------+
```

Comment: Can you please tell logic behind that expected output?

Comment: you would be better using a derived table based upon c = 1 then using the pivot function based on d grouping the results via a

Comment: I dont need multiple rows. so i am expecting it with single row. I need this result set to check the validation t-sql procedure

Answer (score 0):

Do like this (using CTE)

### QUERY

```
    WITH 
    CTE1 as (select top 1 d as T1 from temp where b=1 and c=1),
    CTE2 as (select top 1 d as T2 from temp where b=2 and c=1),
    CTE3 as (select top 1 d as T3 from temp where b=3 and c=1)

    select CTE1.*, CTE2.*, CTE3.*
    FROM CTE1 CROSS JOIN CTE2 CROSS JOIN CTE3
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6932e/2)

[About the multiple CTE](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/08/sql-server-multiple-cte-in-one-select-statement-query/)

Please let me whether it works!

Comment: you have used top 1 which may give correct results for the sample, but the where condition mentioned in query is also important..

Comment: it will work but I don't need "select"  for each case... Do u have any solution?

Comment: Thanks Murtaza
but this is just a sample how he can solve his problem. It's no the exact SQL that he will use.. it gives the idea

Comment: [Thej](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4074077/thej) I am not sure whether there is any other way

Comment: I have 20 case statement like this .. So if I write select for each case then performance will hit.. So I am looking for better solution.

Comment: In that case, you cannot get result in just one row. You will get 20 rows